# How to use IN for search in JSON-b with index?

Tags: postgresql

I have table with JSON-b field like this:

```
id | data
----------
1  | '{"points": [{"id": 10, "address": "Test 1"}, {"id": 20, "address": "Test 2"}, {"id": 30, "address": "Test 3"}]}'
2  | '{"points": [{"id": 40, "address": "Test 444"}, {"id": 20, "address": "Test 222"}, {"id": 50, "address": "Test 555"}]}'
```

The JSON-b field "data" contains "points" array.

How to get all "points" whose point id is contained in an array [40, 20]? Like classic IN:

```
... IN (40,20)
```

Query must use GIN index!!! Array IDs will be sub-query.

Comment: Probably `WHERE data @> '{"points": [{"id": 20}]}}' OR data @> '{"points": [{"id": 40}]}}'`

Comment: IDs 20 and 40 are for example. IDs will be obtained from a subquery (dynamically).

Comment: I guess then you'll need to build those "query objects" dynamically. You might be able to use them in a join (but I don't know whether the join will use the GIN index, or how to compel postgres to do that)

Answer (score 1):

You could almost do it with a functional index using a jsonb_path_query_array to extract the data.  But as far as I can tell, not quite.

```
create index on t using gin (jsonb_path_query_array(x,'$.points[*].id'));
```

And then query with:

```
select * from t where jsonb_path_query_array(x,'$.points[*].id') ?| '{20,40}';
```

The problem is that `?|` only works with *text* elements, while in your data the values of 'id' are integers, not text.  I thought jsonpath would provide a way to convert them to text, but if it does, I cannot find it.

So instead I think you will have to define your own function which accepts jsonb, and returns int[] or text[] (or jsonb which is an array of text conversions).  Then you can build an index on the results of this function.  Don't forget to declare it immutable.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to unnest the array (essentially normalizing your data model "on-the-fly") then you can use a subquery to check the value:

```
select t.*
from the_table t
where exists (select *
              from jsonb_array_elements(t.data -> 'points') as x(element)
              where (x.element ->> 'id')::int in (select id 
                                                  from other_table))
```

Comment: This query will not use GIN index on data->'points'. This will seq scan on full table with billion records. This is unacceptable

Comment: That is true, that's the price you pay for de-normalizing your data.